# Is fstat() a safe (sandboxed) operation?

Tags: python, sandbox, stat, pypy

I'm currently writing a Python sandbox using sandboxed PyPy. Basically, the sandbox works by providing a "controller" that maps system library calls to a specified function instead. After following the instructions found at [codespeak](http://codespeak.net/pypy/dist/pypy/doc/sandbox.html) (which walk through the set up process), I realized that the default controller does not include a replacement for `os.fstat()`, and therefore crashes when I call `open()`. Specifically, the included `pypy/translator/sandbox/sandlib.py` does not contain a definition for `do_ll_os__ll_os_fstat`.

So far, I've implemented it as:

```
def do_ll_os__ll_os_fstat(self, fd):
    return os.fstat(fd)
```

which seems to work fine. Is this safe? Will this create a hole in the sandbox?

Comment: My gut feel is that if you already have an open file-descriptor, getting the stat results isn't likely to provide means to an exploit. This is just an impression, I'd have to think o'nt more.

Comment: That's what I was thinking, too. However, I don't know much about POSIX/Unix/etc, and I *really* don't want things going wrong, so I wanted to ask someone more experienced.

Comment: If the instructions at codespeak are an essential part of your question, it would be better (=more chances to get a response) if you at least summarise them in your question.

Comment: They aren't particularly important; I mentioned them to reference the fact that I followed official documentation, and hence (probably) didn't just screw up the set up process. I'll edit the post.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The fstat call can reveal certain information which you may or may not want to keep secret. Among other things:

- Whether two file descriptors are on the same filesystem
- The block size of the underlying filesystem
- Numeric UID/GIDs of file owners
- Modification/access times of files

However, it will not modify anything, so if you don't mind this (relatively minor) information leak, no problem. You could also alter some of the results to mask information you want to hide (set owner UIDs/GIDs to 0, for example)

Answer (score 3):

bdonlan's answer is good, but since there is a bounty here, what the heck :-)

You can see for yourself precisely what information `fstat` provides by reading the [POSIX spec for struct stat](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/sys_stat.h.html).

It is definitely a "read-only" operation.  And as a rule, Unix file descriptors only provide access to the single object to which they refer.  For example, a (readable) file descriptor referencing a directory will allow you to list the files within the directory, but it will not allow you to *access* files within the directory; for that, you need to `open()` the file, which will perform a permission check.

Be aware that `fstat` can be called on non-files like directories or sockets.  Here again, though, it will only provide the information you see in `struct stat` and it will not modify anything.  (And for a socket, most of the fields will be meaningless.)